# How to set additional options for Chart.js BarCharts using React-Chartkick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, chartkick

I'm trying to display a barchart using React-Chartkick and Chart.js, and I'd like to customise the colours of the bars. Currently, I'm able to set all the bars to the same colour by passing a prop like this: `<BarChart colours={["#fff"]} />`.

Using LineCharts in React-Chartkick, you can set colours of the lines by passing an array of colours through that prop. BarCharts only seems to accept the first colour, however. Is this a limitation of React-Chartkick, or am I doing something wrong?

I've tried passing options (as described here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#styling ) through the `library` prop as that is how I've customised the colours of the axes and labels, but this doesn't seem to affect the bars.

Here's my current code:

```
    state = {
        chartLibraryOptions: {
            borderColor: "#e34402", // does nothing here
            backgroundColor: "#e34402", // nor this
            scales: {
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: { fontColor: "#fff", autoSkip: false }
                    }
                ],
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: { fontColor: "#fff" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <BarChart
                data={this.state.chartData}
                library={this.state.chartLibraryOptions}
                colors={["#e34402", "#e3b502"]} // All bars are the first colour
            />
        );
    }
```

I'm expecting to be able to change the colours of each bar, but after all this I'm not sure if that's possible through Chartkick?

Comment: did you try backgroundColor?

Comment: I have, both as a prop and as an option in chartLibraryOptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I used the same node package in a project with different approach kinda work for me. Almost all the charts take the same attributes.

Basically, this attribute `dataset={{ backgroundColor: ['white', 'yellow' ], }}`
is all you need to colour each `bar`. You can either pass string or array of string to backgroundColor.

The `backgroundColor` in dataset takes two types of data `String` and `Array(object)`. Typical examples of passing data are below.

1. When you set `backgroundColor` to a string, it applied the same colour to each bar. e.g `backgroundColor: 'red'`

> BarChart -  `<BarChart dataset={{ backgroundColor: 'red', }} />`

[image: bar chart one color]]

2. When you set `backgroundColor` to an array, it applied each colour in the array to each bar. e.g `backgroundColor: ['red', 'yellow']`, then you create a loop of colours base on the data length.

> column chart - `<ColumnChart dataset={{ backgroundColor: ['red', 'yellow' ], }} />`

[image]

React Implementation Below:

```
/* eslint-disable no-plusplus */
 import React from 'react';
 import { ColumnChart, BarChart } from 'react-chartkick';
 import { chartOne } from '../common/chartData';
 import 'chart.js';

 const MonthlyGrowth = () => {
    const handleBgColors = () => {
       const firstColor = "#A00B16", secondColor = "#FAA226";
       const arrOfBgColors = [];
       for (let i = 1; i <= chartOne.length; i++) {
           if (i % 2 === 0) {
              arrOfBgColors.push(secondColor)
           } else {arrOfBgColors.push(firstColor)}
       }
       return arrOfBgColors;
   }

   return (
     <div className="bukka-card uk-card-default bg-white pt-4 pb-2 mr-1 pl-3 pr-2 pl- 
       lg-5">
        <h2 className="mt-2">4,500,000</h2>
        <BarChart
           dataset={{ borderWidth: 0, width: 0, backgroundColor: handleBgColors(), }}
           data={chartOne}
        />
      </div>
    )
}

export default MonthlyGrowth;
```